# What standard should we set for questions tagged "Plutus-Pioneer"?

Tags: discussion

There are a large influx of new users here when a new cohort starts on the "Plutus pioneer" course.  It leads to a lot of new questions that do not come close to the guidelines set out in the tour and the help center.

Which guidelines should we be particularly focused on enforcing and encouraging?

Answer (score 1):

1- to look for previous similar questions (many questions are repeated).

2- to stick to plutus-related questions as all haskell questions (syntax etc) should be asked in other forums.

Other than that there are many entry level questions that are valid and healthy for an ecosystem like this one.

In addition, please let's also remember that in the PPP classes, it is encouraged to post All questions in this platform (for the live sessions, like an Ask Me Anything).

One more solution is to ask the ppp team to also communicate the standards to the ppp cohorts, either using those guidelines from the Tour, or refining them further based on additional previous non-compliant examples not covered in the tour.

**Call for action:**

Can then all moderators gather/synthetize what types of questions are not too good? this thread can be used for gathering such types.

Comment: I have already reached out to the PPP program and asked that they suggest several steps/standards for using this site early in the program.  I don't know if they will take any or all on-board.

Comment: Great! I think it should be an iterative process as this community is just so new (all actors). Do you have examples of recent not too good questions? (not to point fingers but an example).

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've deleted the other entry

Comment: The questions can be edited, so pointing at specific examples doesn't necessarily remain a valid criticism.

Comment: Too many PPP questions seem to be generic questions that are more about github, git, setting up an environment.  Worst case seem to be "this threw an error", large dump of screenshots/logs, "help me!/do I need help?".

Comment: I have been in IT industry for decades and I wouldn't be so slack/clueless in public.  When I post here, I put in a lot of effort to be as concise, accurate and professional as possible.

Comment: I think what we should promote is the standards set in [ask], [answer] and the article in the help called "What questions should I avoid asking?"